# How to increase the height of UITableView dynamically as per TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift

If I want to change the height of UITableView as per the cell content changes i.e. the height of UITableViewCell increase as API response come different every time? 
Please help me to find out a solution?

Comment: Take the outlet of height constraint of tableView in viewController, then calculate the height and assign to that constraint, e.g. self.heightConstraint.constant = 200;

Comment: Do you not want the table view to be scrolling ?

Comment: @Tushar Sharma :
Not give the proper solution as I want, Please check?

Comment: @GoodSp33d :
I don't want to be height fix & it will changes as per tableview cell content height.

Comment: check auto layout for uitbaleviewcell with label having number of line as Zero

Comment: @Kiranjadhav, what type of content you want to display with dynamic height? Label, images, and other?

Comment: @ Kuldeep:
UIlabel[Name] + UILabel[Count] + UIImage[icon]

Answer (score 2):

If your receiving response in array then you can increase the height with array counts by reload your table view `tableView.reloadData()` when you are receiving the responses.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

 if indexPath.section == 0 {
  switch indexPath.row {
  case 0:
    return 50
  case 1:
    return 60
  case 2:
    if array.count > 0{
      return (CGFloat(45* array.count))
    }else{
      return 0
    }
   default:
    return 0
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let key = arrInfo[indexPath.row]["key"] as! String
        print("height for row key \(key)")
        if key == "CasinoInfo"{
            return 100  
        }
        else if key == "Ratings"{
            return 180
        }
        else if key == "Bonus"{
            return 120
        }
        else{
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }

        return 0
    }
```